# How to update a view in android

Tags: android

I am using the existing code from the repository: 
https://github.com/webianks/msgs
And trying to modify it. This is an SMS app. The main view which shows all the SMS is 
[image]

Inside the AllConversationAdapter.kt there is a function     `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {` 
which is populating the SMS in the view. When it reaches there I make an HTTP call 
with the SMS as post data and get a response 0 or 1 depending upon the SMS type 
Basically, I am categorizing the SMS into two different types.
But till the time I get the response, all the SMS will be loaded into the view.
So I want to indicate those messages for which my API returned one say with a 
the simple red dot on the top right corner. How do I do that? Is that possible to modify the view 
 Any hints or approach I could take?

**Some more Thoughts:** 
I figured out that the following XML is what getting displayed for each SMS in the above SMS view

https://github.com/webianks/msgs/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/single_sms_small_layout.xml

So for those SMS I want to show a red dot I could simply create 
one more XML with the red dot and use that template. That 
could be one approach. But since API call will take some time 
to return the response it will be preferable to update only those 
sms with a dot for which API returned 1. This is a place I block 
How do I get access to what is getting displayed and update it
programmatically or replace it with a different XML totally. 
Not sure if there is a way to identify the sms's that are displayed 
and update them

Answer (score 0):

Don't use more than one XML for such a simple UI change.

Add an ImageView with the red dot in the place you want it to be in `single_sms_small_layout.xml` with the property `android:visibility="gone"`.

When the API returns 1 change the visibility of the view programmatically with `imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Notify the adapter with [notifiyItemChanged(Int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int)) if needed (depends on your implementation).

Comment: Thanks. I added a red dot svg and it's appearing on all messages as of now. After setting visibility as gone it disappears. So this small part is working properly. But inside the function when I tried to fetch the particular imageview like `(this.context as AppCompatActivity).findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.redDot)` It returned null. I am not sure why that could be the case. The file is https://github.com/webianks/msgs/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/webianks/hatkemessenger/adapters/AllConversationAdapter.kt and I am writing this findViewByID inside the function `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: I'm not user what `this` is referring to, the Adapter? The adapter class doesn't have any context as a property and it certainly isn't an AppCompatActivity. Each dot is inside of each holder's view so do `holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.redDot)` inside of `onBindViewHolder(..)`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I didn't need to call notifiyItemChanged(Int). Not sure what could be the reason for that.